# What's the correct use of new Java 7 Path class?

Tags: java

I currently use this approach to load files in my applications:

```
Path path = Paths.get(ClassLoader.class.getResource(fileName).toURI());
```

where fileName is structured as "/package1/package2/folder/file.lol".

Are there better, simpler, or more correct methods to get a Path object?
I need that works inside JARs too.

Comment: Did you check the javadoc? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html

Comment: @ftr yes i checked it, and this too http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/pathClass.html, but they don't contain an answer to my question

Comment: @TheEliteGentleman we are costantly looking to improve our code, aren't we? :)

Comment: The [class use](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/class-use/Path.html) page answers your question completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access a file which is not in a jar, then there is better solutions. But since it seems that you want to access that is part of a jar, I would say no!